# SQL join on non-present lines

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables as follow:

```
 position
 --------------------------------
  position_id    description     
     17            team_lead     
     18            accountant    
     19            it_specialist 
     20            consultant 
 --------------------------------

assignment
------------------------------------------------------------
 position_id      people_id     start          stop
    17               1001         2020-01-01     2021-06-01
    17               1002         2021-06-01     2021-08-01
    18               1003         2020-01-01     2021-12-01
    19               1004         2020-01-01     2021-08-01
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to retrieve the positions that have no assignment today (2021-08-12), regardless if they had past assignments or not. The expected output should be:

```
  position_id    
     17
     19
     20
```

How can I do this ? My attempts to use a `left join` like:

```
select
    position.position_id
from position
left join assignment
on
    assignment.position_id = position.position_id
where
    /* incorrect. How to match a non-interval ? */
    assignment.start >= DATE('now') or assignment.stop <= DATE('now')
```

fail to properly match what I want.

Comment: whould you show us the sql statement you've tried?

Comment: Can you please share the desired output?

Comment: @DmitryGrekov updated question accordingly

Comment: @DrGenius updated question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select p.*
from positions p
where not exists (select 1
                  from assignments a
                  where a.position_id = p.position_id and
                        a.start <= current_date and
                        a.stop >= current_date
                 );
```

It is not clear from your question is the stop date is included.  That would affect the last comparison.

Comment: stop date is excluded, but `not exists` is what I should have used.